# React Router - Stylesheet getting marked as "text/html" when adding a variable route (/:userId)

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, react-router

Our custom stylsheet "styles.css" is getting marked with the incorrect MIME type "text/html" even thought it has:

```
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
```

This error only occurs when going to routes with a variable parameter like /:userId

The exact error is:

> The stylesheet http://localhost:3000/user/static/styles/styles.css was
>   not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

Router Code:

```
ReactDom.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={MainLayout}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/main" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/user/:userId" component={UserSetting} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

Is it possible that this is simply some configuration that I need to account for on our express server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a simple oversight on my part. In my index.html i was missing a slash for my path starting at static.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/styles/styles.css">
```

To

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles/styles.css">
```